# JPanel enemy objects not loading

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jpanel, paint

Long story short, I am attempting to create a java multiplayer game. I am trying to create a JPanel battle animation scene.. I have the battlescreen pop-up when server sends client an attack message... but nothing loads and I am getting a nullpointer exception which I don't know how to solve.

Main Class -> Has a handleAttackMessageFromServer(String msg) method

this method loads a new Jframe which has an object which extends JPanel

> FightFrame(msg){ FightSceneJPanel(msg)}

My code for the JPanel where I am trying to load gifs of enemy units:

```
public class FightScene extends JPanel{
private ArrayList<Enemy> offense;
private ArrayList<Defense> defense;
private EnemyFactory enemyFactory;
private DefenseFactory defenseFactory;
private boolean ingame;
int NumberOfEnemyTypeA, ..., NumberOfEnemyTypeN;

public FightScene(){

offense = new ArrayList<Enemy>();
defense = new ArrayList<Defense>();

setFocusable(true);
setBackground(Color.RED);
setDoubleBuffered(true);
setSize(652, 480);
    setVisible(true);

enemyFactory = new EnemyFactory();
defenseFactory= new DefenseFactory();
}

public void FightScene(String attackmsg){
ingame=true;

// string parsing to figure out how many of what units were sent over
NumberOfEnemyTypeA = Integer.parseint(msg.(....)));
// ...
NumberOFEnemyTypeN = Integer.parseint(msg.(...)));
if(NumberOfEnemyTypeA!=0){
        for (int i =1;i<NumberOfEnemyTypeA+1;i++){
            theEnemy=enemyFactory.makeEnemy(1, 0-i*40);
             offense.add(theEnemy);
        }}

System.out.println("Offense size: "+offense.size()); // <<< When i do this, it says offense //size is 0!!.. even when NumberOFEnemyTypeA is 5, 10 or any number>0
}

// and when i try to draw... I get nothing, because ofcourse offense == 0
public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        for (int i = 0; i < offense.size(); i++) {
                if(offense.get(i) instanceof EnemyTypeA){
                    EnemyTypeA a = (EnemyTypeA)offense.get(i);
                    if(a.isVisible()){ 
                        g2d.drawImage(a.getImage(), a.getX(), a.getY(), this);
                        }
                }
// ....
                if(offense.get(i) instanceof EnemyTypeN){
                    EnemyTypeN a = (EnemyTypeN)offense.get(i);
                    if(a.isVisible()){ 
                        g2d.drawImage(a.getImage(), a.getX(), a.getY(), this);
                        }
                }
}
}
```

Can't figure out whats going on!!!

Below is how the Frame loads the ScenePanel, but FightFrame itself is invoked in the HandleServerAttackMessage() in the main method.

```
public void FightFrame(String offensemsg){
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("BattleView: ");
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            FightScene sc = new FightScene();
            sc.Scene(offensemsg);

            frame.add(sc);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setSize(652, 480);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setResizable(false);
        }
```

Comment: Could you add the stacktrace with the line of code which causes `NullPointerException` to be thrown?

Comment: @MadProgrammer that's not a constructor... The OP should remove the void from it. Or... I'm not actually sure. He definitely shouldn't be naming methods like they're constructors.

Comment: I tried this() in the FightScene(String) constructor...

`System.out.println("Offense size: "+offense.size());` is still giving me 0 as offense.size() output

Comment: I tried as constructor and as a method with same name as constructor (because i wanted it to load when this object loaded) but neither work

Comment: @BorisPavlović the nullpointer exception is coming from

 `for (int i = 0; i < offense.size(); i++) {` most likely because offense.size() ==0

Comment: that's not `offense.size()` that is 0, but `offense == null`

Comment: Don't override `paint()` for swing components. Override `paintComponent()` instead and call `repaint()` when you need to draw the changes.

Comment: I think the paint() is not the issue because offense.size()==0 and my paint method relies on that to draw images.. so if offense.size() = 0 then there is nothing to paint.. even tho I passed attackmessage to show 10 units

Comment: If you get a NPE at that line, then `offense == null`, and as such does not have size. You either assign it to `null` somewhere or shadow it with another declaration.

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) You've described a problem and how you can't do it, but have so far not asked a question (let alone a specific, answerable question).  What *is* your question? 4) A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough.

Comment: @user2556304 1) *I think the `paint()` is not the issue*, **MAYBE** so either way its bad practice use `paintComponent(..)`. 2) Also dont use `setSize` rather override `JPanel#getPreferredSize` and call `pack()` on `JFrame` before setting it visible. 3) Also have a read on [Game Development Loop, Logic and Collision detection Java Swing 2D](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/code/444547/game-development-loop-logic-and-collision-detection-java-swing-2d) has a simple library which has most methods etc needed for a simple 2D game with animations, can be used or edited to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

JPanel needs to be inserted in a top level Container, such as JFrame.

Is your pop up window a JFrame?
Can you show us the code that add the JPanel to the Jframe?

Comment: is the expression correct in the second parameter?
I don't know how your makeEnemy works, but it seems odd 0-....

theEnemy=enemyFactory.makeEnemy(1, 0-i*40);

Comment: This is my own custom enemyfactory i made, and it works.. this is not the issue

enemyFactory.makeEnemy(type,starting x-location-on-panel)

Comment: this may be trivial, but have you checked that it parses NumberOfEnemyTypeA correctly? Adding for example a print of i inside the for loop where you create Enemy?

Comment: I just saw the new piece of code you added: can you add sc.Scene(offensemsg); at the end of the instructions after you have made the panels visible?

Comment: yep, checked the parse, works fine...

`System.out.println(NumberOfEnemyTypeA); // gives 100 (when passed 100 from server)`

`if(NumberOfEnemyTypeA!=0){
  for (int i =1;i<NumberOfEnemyTypeA+1;i++){
   theEnemy=(EnemyA) enemyFactory.makeEnemy(1, 0-i*40);
    offense.add(theEnemy);
  }}`

and when I try:

`System.out.println("Offense size: "+offense.size());
`

I still get 0 for offense.size()

Comment: For sure there is something wrong there, since offence.size() is 0. If it goes through the for loop and the size doesn't change, maybe the add function doesn't work, and that can be because the parameter is wrong somehow. Is theEnemy null?

Comment: You also have sc.Scene(offensemsg); in the code you have the method public void FightScene(String attackmsg){}, I assume you also have a Scene() method ... right?